# TinyMCE setting mail content from outlook 2013, mso tags, numberd list position

Tags: javascript, email, outlook, tinymce, ms-office

We have developed a mail client in Java. For rendering the HTML we use DJBrowser. http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/. For the editor we embedded TinyMCE into the DJBrowser.
We receive a mail generated by outlook 2013, which contains a numbered list. The outlook generates a HTML body containing mso tags as following:

```
  <html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
  xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">
<style>
<!-- 
..
```

An item in the numbered list has the HTML source

```
<p class=MsoListParagraph style='text-indent:-18.0pt;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'><![if !supportLists]><span style='mso-list:Ignore'>1.<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New..
```

If we store the generated content as html file and open with Internet Explorer, no problem. Or if we set this content to the DJBrowser, again no problem. (Client is reading and viewing mails, not editing at this time).

Problem occurs when user wants to reply or forward, we have to switch to editable mode, we set the content above to the TinyMCE instance with the setContent method of TinyMCE.

After setting the content, we cannot see the numbers of the numbered list, because the style in the class MsyListParagprag text-indent:-18.0pt makes them to move too much on the left of the textarea and the numbers are not visible any more.

The same problem also occurs when running TinyMCE and toggling to the HTML source window, and setting the content. Again the list items are far beyond on the left and not visible.

How can we solve this issue? I think
- we can replace the mso tags by some reg. expressions
- can i use the pastefromword concept? Here we do not perform any paste, we directly set the content using setContent method.
- why do we see the items in correct position when not using TinyMCE (when open the produced html by the outlook, we can see items)